# Recursive extension of a variable in c#

Tags: c#, variables, implementation

I need to implement a program where I will have a base variable `x` and its extensions like `exp(x), ln(x), exp(5ln(x))` etc. I have thought of having an interface `IExtensible`, but I'm not sure how to implement the variables. The option I have considered is using some list for keeping the sequence and type of extensions. But I'm not sure this kind of implementation will be easy to deal with: I need to use these extensions as variables in a rational function.

EDIT: I've added a small sample of what I need to have in the end:

> x^2 + 3exp(ln(2x)) - ln(x^4)

This kind of expression is passed to a function `F` which will perform some calculations.
The function `F` needs to know exactly what extensions there are.

Comment: @Matthias Koch, It's a long story )))

Comment: By extensions, do you mean operations on some variable x?  I'm guessing you want to use these to build some kind of expression to manipulate or evaluate, rather than just using the built-in Math methods for ln and exp

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far, provide an example of what you want your program to do, and maybe also phrase this as a question? It it rather hard to understand what you are asking, and it's a pity, because it looks interesting.

Comment: I think you are using non-standard terminology (Google brings me back to this question). It appears you want to implement some kind of series, what is it exactly?

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco, I've added a small sample of what I'm trying to do. Hope the edit will make me more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a math parser and it so happens I created a math parser for .NET and you can download it [from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274093/Math-Parser-NET). It has full source code and it lets you set up custom delegate functions for creating built in operations. In addition it has variable support so you can define a variable (such as `x` in your example) and you can make that variable equal anything you want. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to gather what exactly it is you're asking here, but it sounds like you might want to use some anonymous functions to define your "extensions", then you could store them in a look-up table like you said:

Here is some basic sample code, with one recursive example, to demonstrate the idea:

```
Func<long,long> sqr = 
    ( x ) => 
    { 
        return x * x;
    };

Func<long,long> factoral = 
    ( n ) =>
    {
        return n > 1 ? 
            n * ( long )( MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Invoke( null, new object[] { n - 1 } ) ) :
            n;
    };

var DataObjects = new []
{
    new { Name = "sqr(1)!", Value = factoral( sqr( 1 ) ) },
    new { Name = "sqr(2)!", Value = factoral( sqr( 2 ) ) },
    new { Name = "sqr(3)!", Value = factoral( sqr( 3 ) ) },
    new { Name = "sqr(4)!", Value = factoral( sqr( 4 ) ) },
    new { Name = "sqr(5)!", Value = factoral( sqr( 5 ) ) },
};

DataObjects.ToList().ForEach
(
    d =>
        Console.WriteLine( d )
);
```

Yields the output:

Name sqr(1)! 
Value 1

Name sqr(2)!
Value 24

Name sqr(3)!
Value 362880

Name sqr(4)!
Value 20922789888000

Name sqr(5)!
Value 7034535277573963776

Hope this helps,